# How to delete a file that contains spaces in the file name?

Tags: windows-7

I have a file with this name "Registering wrong app ", there are a few spaces in the file name, now I can't delete it, it won't even let me change file name, I also tried to delete it from my Java program, it won't let me either, how to delete it?

When deleting it from Explorer, I got this:

```
Could not find this item
This is no longer located in C:\My_Dir\.
Verify the item's location and try again.

Registering wrong app
Type: File
Siz: 0 bytes
```

The strange thing is, this file is invisible to the system, it's 0 in size and has space in its name.

Comment: What message do you get when you try to delete it from Explorer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
del /F "\\?\C:\My_Dir\Registering*wrong*app*"
```

This will match any amount of characters between and after the words, and also works on wrong files.

If you don't have other files that start with `Registering`, you might as well try:

```
del /F "\\?\C:\My_Dir\Registering*"
```

---

If the file is undeletable, use [**Process Explorer**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) and search for the handle and kill the owning process.

> Find --> Find Handle/DLL (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) --> Type in `Registering` --> Kill the matching processes.

Comment: instead of Process Explorer,use "unlocker" (ccollomb.free.fr)

Comment: instead of [unlocker](http://filedb.experts-exchange.com/incoming/2009/11_w46/200590/Ccollomb.free.fr-site-unsafe-war.bmp), use **"Process Explorer" ([Microsoft Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default))**, safe and useful ;-)

Comment: Man, this answer takes me back to the DOS 3.1 days.  Can always "drop to DOS" (now a command box).  Thanks for the effective nostalgia.

Answer (score 9):

Open a command prompt, and change to the My_Dir directory

```
cd \My_Dir
```

Get the short (8.3) file name for the file.

```
dir /a /x /p
```

You should see something like

```
02/13/2011  07:25 PM             1,010 REGIST~1     Registering Wrong App
```

The **REGIST~1** is the short file name. Try the **del** command with that name.

```
del REGIST~1
```

Comment: This answer (with short names) is wonderful and much simpler than the above solutions with additional programmes! I don't know why it wasn't accepted. Anyway, it worked for me (do delete a folder with the trailing space in name, created by Dropbox probably), thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. There are many reasons why one answer gets accepted over another. Part of the beauty of Stack Exchange is that even the answers that aren't accepted stay up, so people with similar problems can stumble across them later.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the filename in quotes, but replacing the spaces with question marks, like this:

del "registering?wrong?app"

That should delete the file if the spaces aren't really spaces, but nulls or some other invisible character.

Answer (score 1):

Spaces shouldn't matter if you are trying to delete the file from Explorer. If you are trying to delete from the command line simply put the file name in quotes like this `del "Registering wrong app "`.

If this does not work you have something else holding you up other than spaces in the file name... like a process that is "locking" the file, thus preventing deletion.

Answer (score 1):

Delete dirs or files with a space in it:

```
dir /a /x/ /p

"files or dirs with space"

c:\DIR1WITHSPACE~1
c:\DIR2WITHSPACE~2

ren DIRWITHSPACE~1 TEST

del test

"Job done...."
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who still could not get this to work (like me). Using the 7zip file explorer to rename the file works. It appears to perform a more low level rename than windows allows.