# How do I delete a folder where the filename was generated by ALT bashing?

Tags: windows-vista

I made a folder nameless by holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key and typing some numbers. It's not a file with spaces that's the problem. It's that the filename doesn't display anything.

Now I can't rename or delete it. I can only move it.

Is there any way to delete it?

Comment: What operating system / version?

Comment: What OS? Is it a system folder? What error do you get when you try and delete it? Your question is way too vague.

Comment: I am using windows Vista and it is not a system folder. And I do not get any error, just the folder wont go anywhere when I delete it.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to delete file with spaces in file name on Win 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/245441/how-to-delete-file-with-spaces-in-file-name-on-win-7)

Answer (score 4):

Move your nameless folder into another directory (parent) that you don't mind loosing (just create a new folder, hell leave the name as "New Folder"), then delete the parent. Your nameless folder will be deleted with it.

Comment: +1 Don't understand why this was down-voted as it should work

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to get rid of that nameless folder. Try the following.

- Step 1: On desktop, right click and select *New WinRAR archive*, press Enter.
- Step 2: Open the new archive.
- Step 3: Add the nameless folder to it. While adding select "Delete the source file after archiving" option, and click OK.
- Step 4: Now the nameless folder comes into the WinRAR archive and gets deleted from where it has been earlier.
- Step 5: Delete the created WinRAR archive.

Comment: -1 This requires a paid program.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into command prompt, you can do `dir /X` which will list shortnames for the folders. Then you can just do `rd [shortname] /S /Q` and you should be good to go.