# How to delete a file with quotes and spaces in the name without short name

Tags: windows

The file doesn't have the short name (shown by `del /x`), answers here didn't help: [How to delete a file that contains spaces in the file name?](https://superuser.com/questions/245441/how-to-delete-a-file-that-contains-spaces-in-the-file-name)

On attempt to `del /F` via pattern and `\\?\` prefix it says "the filename,directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect".

Comment: Please show us the command you tried to use.

Comment: @DourHighArch `del /F "\\?\D:\FileNameStartBeforeSpacesAndQuotes*"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a bash shell then you can use the rm command and start to type the name of the file and then use tab to autocomplete the filename. This should easily allow you to get at the escaped spaces or quotes.

Comment: 1) It's Windows 2) The problem is much deeper